# Remove constraint validation in DateType fields in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have an entity with a date field , my problem is that I want to give the possibility a user to leave the fields month and year was null.
and so I want to completely remove the constraint validation in my date field

how do I do that?

Here are my fields

```
    ->add('datefield', DateType::class, array(
        'data' => new \DateTime(),
        'format' => 'dd MMMM yyyy',
        'required' => false,
        'placeholder' => array(
            'month' => 'empty',
            'year' => 'empty'
        )
    ))
```

and my entity

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datefield", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $datefield;
```

this is my error

```
This value is not valid.    datefield    Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[datefield] = [year => null, month => null, day => 18]

Caused by: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "datefield": The fields "year", "month" should not be empty

Caused by: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

The fields "year", "month" should not be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried null values like so:

```
->add('datefield', DateType::class, array(
    'data'          => new \DateTime(),
    'format'            => 'dd MMMM yyyy',
    'required'      => false,
    'placeholder'   => array(
        'month' => null,
        'year'  => null,
    ),
))
```

I'm not sure if this will fix the problem. Try it.